# kolla_toolbox container is not running during kolla-ansible deployment of xena openstack

Tags: openstack

could anyone help me resolve this error. Stackoverflow didn't help on this!

```
fatal: [controller1]: FAILED! => {
    "changed": false
}

MSG: kolla_toolbox container is not running.
```

I got this error during `kolla-ansible -i multinode deploy` command. Please help, someone!

Update1: I ran `kolla-ansible pull -i multinode` and got the following error:

```
changed: [block1] => (item=iscsid)
FAILED - RETRYING: iscsi | Pull images (3 retries left).
FAILED - RETRYING: iscsi | Pull images (2 retries left).
FAILED - RETRYING: iscsi | Pull images (1 retries left).
failed: [block1] (item=tgtd) => {
    "ansible_loop_var": "item",
    "attempts": 3,
    "changed": true,
    "item": {
        "key": "tgtd",
        "value": {
            "container_name": "tgtd",
            "dimensions": {},
            "enabled": true,
            "group": "tgtd",
            "image": "quay.io/openstack.kolla/centos-binary-tgtd:xena",
            "ipc_mode": "host",
            "privileged": true,
            "volumes": [
                "/etc/kolla/tgtd/:/var/lib/kolla/config_files/:ro",
                "kolla_logs:/var/log/kolla/",
                "/etc/localtime:/etc/localtime:ro",
                "/etc/timezone:/etc/timezone:ro",
                "/dev/:/dev/",
                "/run/:/run/:shared",
                "/lib/modules:/lib/modules:ro",
                "/sys/kernel/config:/configfs",
                "cinder:/var/lib/cinder",
                "iscsi_info:/etc/iscsi"
            ]
        }
    }
}
```

```
MSG:
'Traceback (most recent call last):\n
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/dist-packages/docker/api/client.py", line 268, in _raise_for_status\n
    response.raise_for_status()\n
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/requests/models.py", line 940, in raise_for_status\n
    raise HTTPError(http_error_msg, response=self)\n
  requests.exceptions.HTTPError: 404 Client Error: Not Found for url:
  http+docker://localhost/v1.41/images/create?tag=xena&fromImage=quay.io%2Fopenstack.kolla%2Fcentos-binary-tgtd
  \n\nDuring handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:
  \n\nTraceback (most recent call last):\n
  File "/tmp/ansible_kolla_docker_payload_3x_7vki7/ansible_kolla_docker_payload.zip/ansible/modules/kolla_docker.py", line 1241, in main\n
  File "/tmp/ansible_kolla_docker_payload_3x_7vki7/ansible_kolla_docker_payload.zip/ansible/modules/kolla_docker.py", line 691, in pull_image\n  
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/dist-packages/docker/api/image.py", line 430, in pull\n
    self._raise_for_status(response)\n  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/dist-packages/docker/api/client.py", line 270, in _raise_for_status\n
    raise create_api_error_from_http_exception(e)\n
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/dist-packages/docker/errors.py", line 31, in create_api_error_from_http_exception\n
    raise cls(e, response=response, explanation=explanation)\n
  docker.errors.NotFound: 404 Client Error for 
  http+docker://localhost/v1.41/images/create?
 tag=xena&fromImage=quay.io%2Fopenstack.kolla%2Fcentos-binary-tgtd: 
 Not Found ("manifest for quay.io/openstack.kolla/centos-binary-tgtd:xena not found: manifest unknown: manifest unknown")\n'
[WARNING]: Could not match supplied host pattern, ignoring: enable_multipathd_True
```

Comment: `bootstrap-servers` and `prechecks`, `pull` commands are work fine ?

Comment: Hi! Sorry for late response. I was trying to debug. Everything except pull is working fine. In case of pull, there's just one traceback error from python script in only one node(block node).

Comment: According to this error message `kolla_toolbox container is not running.`, you should check the log of kolla_toolbox container.

Comment: And what's the error tips of `traceback error from python script in only one node(block node)`? Could you post to the question?

Comment: Hi @VictorLee! Thanks for your reply. I've updated the traceback. But I guess, it's not something serious. However, at the end of deployment, the message I get is "kolla_toolbox container is not running" and the deployment fails!

Comment: Also, I ran 

openstack@controller1:~$ sudo docker logs kolla_toolbox
Error: No such container: kolla_toolbox

Comment: Ok I was able to fix the traceback error from kolla-ansible pull -i multinode command. It was due to  enable_cinder_backend_iscsi was also yes when enable_cinder_backend_lvm was yes on global.yml. They were conflicting according to https://docs.openstack.org/kolla-ansible/queens/reference/cinder-guide.html.

But "kolla_toolbox container is not running." error is still not fixed!

Comment: Are you sure the image `kolla_toolbox` had been pull success? Maybe you should try to `docker rmi kolla-toolbox` and pull it again.

Comment: Ok, I was able to solve this issue by using the latest version of the kolla-ansible globals.yml(Earlier, I was using an old sample globals.yml from a tutorial).